# Civi Upgrade Error when upgrade from 5.66.2 to 5.70

Tags: upgrade

Upgrade fails below error

```
CRM_Core_Exception: 1265 ALTER TABLE `civicrm_managed` CHANGE `cleanup` `cleanup` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'always' COMMENT 'Policy on when to cleanup entity (always, never, unused)' [nativecode=1265 ** Data truncated for column 'cleanup' at row 62] in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php on line 101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the database with below query before the upgrade and then run Civi update

```
UPDATE civicrm_managed
SET cleanup = 'always'
WHERE cleanup IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you Pradeep. I set cleanup to never

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some weird data in that column. The new maxlength is 16 which is plenty long for the 3 possible values (always, never, or unused). Can you check your existing data & see what's in there?

Comment: Yeah, seems to be odd data in civicrm_managed table. It was set to NULL changed it to never using sql query